Can the $r^2$ in gravity be seen as signifying the distance of object 1 to 2 times distance from object 2 to 1
If the formula for gravity multiplies the mass in the numerator and the distance in the denominator is this akin to saying the multiplied masses over the multiplied distances times the gravitational constant, (although the distance both ways is the same hence $r^2$) is this why the law is inverse squared?

what do you mean by "multiplied distances". There is only one distance $r$ and that is the distance between the center of masses of the two objects.

I mean is the reason you square r because when you multiple mass of object 1 by object 2 you not only put the denominator as the distance of object 1 to object 2 but multiply that by the distance of object 2 to object 1 even though the distance is the same forward and backward? I want to know the reason Newtonian gravity follows an inverse square law and if that is a correct interpretation

I would not agree with this interpretation. The $r^2$-law is rather motivated by the spherical symmetry of the problem. The surfaces of constant gravitational force generated by a massive${}^{1)}$ object are spheres. The surface of a sphere is proportional to $r^2$.
${\scriptsize {}^{1)} \text{pointlike or spherically symmetric}}$

It may be more intuitive to consider a more tangible example, e.g. a lightbulb that radiates photons isotropically (i.e. in no prefered direction). The lightbulb may be assumed to be spherically symmetric.
Say now, that at some time $t_0$ the lightbulb emits $N$ photons. Photons travel at the constant speed of light $c$, therefore all photons that were emitted that time $t_0$ must be at the same distance (say $r$) from the source at some later time $t_1$. So they are all located on a sphere of radius $r$ around the lightbulb. Since a sphere has surface area $4\pi r^2$, the density of these photons on this sphere of radius $r$ is $ N / (4\pi r^2)$.
The number of photons emitted at a given time may not always be $N$, however their density at some chosen distance to the source is always proportional to $r^{-2}$, simply due to the geometry of this problem; the spherical symmetry.
Similarly, one can motivate the inverse $r^2$-law for the gravitational field. A massive object "sends out" gravitational force that "becomes less dense" the farther it recedes from its source. Analogously, other spherically symmetric problems follow an inverse $r^2$-law, e.g. Coulomb's law, the intensity of radioactive decay etc. It all boils down to a question of geometry.

EDIT: This claim may be adapted to problems of different geometry. Consider e.g. not a spherically symmetric source of gravity, but rather a cylindrical one. In that case, the force is proportional to $r^{-1}$, since the lateral area of a cylinder is $\propto 2\pi r$.
